# Upgrading from 2.79, objects listed in hierarchy, but nothing showing in 3d view

Tags: objects

I upgraded from 2.79, while some files load in just fine, some of my more recent ones load with no errors, but do not show anything in the 3D view? The items are listed in the hierarchy view, but I can't see or edit them in 3d view. [image]

Comment: This might help: https://blenderartists.org/t/prevent-data-loss-when-transferring-from-blender-2-79-to-2-8/1171855

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your collection is disabled in the viewport. Not sure if there is a shortcut to enable or not.

[image]